# inserting nested for loop (What i am doing wrong )

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

### My Model

inserting only 2 rows in content_for table

```
public function add($data, $content_role = array()) {    
    $this->db->insert_batch('contents', $data);        
    $count      = count($data);
    $insert_id  = $this->db->insert_id();  // Returning ID
    $last_id    = $insert_id + ($count-1);
    $f_data     = $insert_id;
    $l_data     = $last_id;

    if (isset($content_role) && !empty($content_role)) {
        while($f_data <= $l_data) {                
            $total_rec = count($content_role);                
            for ($i = 0; $i < $total_rec; $i++) {
                $content_role[$i]['content_id'] = $insert_id;
            }
            $f_data++;
        }

        $this->db->insert_batch('content_for', $content_role);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your `for` loop is always overwriting previous iteration values in array. Is that intended? Why you need these loops?

Comment: There is something wrong with content_role, try to print content_role maybe you will get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The conditions in your if statement are never true.  You're initializing an empty array when you call the function.  It's never set and always empty.  No reason to even check it if your'e going to do that.

```
<?php

    $content_role = array();

    if (isset($content_role) && !empty($content_role)) {
    echo 'You will never see me';        
    }else{
    echo 'Never set and always empty';    //You'll only ever get this
    }

?>
```